# Pretty JSON not writing correctly in R

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I am writing JSON files from R using the jsonlite package. I would like to use pretty printing, but the results are coming out wrong, with lots of unexpected [ and \ in the text rather than starting a new line.

A simple example:

```
ls <- list(fruit = c("apples", "oranges"), animals = c("cats","dogs"))
ls <- jsonlite::toJSON(ls, pretty = TRUE)
```

This seems to work from within R:

```
ls

{
  "fruit": ["apples", "oranges"],
  "animals": ["cats", "dogs"]
}
```

But is I write out the file:

```
jsonlite::write_json(ls,"test.json", pretty = TRUE)
```

Then I get:

```
["{\n  \"fruit\": [\"apples\", \"oranges\"],\n  \"animals\": [\"cats\", \"dogs\"]\n}"]
```

I'm using R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23) on Windows 10 64 Bit

Comment: Pretty sure this is just a function of how your text editor is interpreting the file. What are you opening the file in after you create it?

Comment: If I run `jsonlite::write_json(ls,"test.json", pretty = TRUE)` and open in either Notepad or Sublime Text, it's formatted as you want.

Comment: Also, you're missing `pretty = TRUE` in `write_json` is that all your issue is?

Comment: @ Mako212 I tried Notepad, Wordpad, Notepad++, and chrome all got the same result

Comment: I tried adding the `pretty = TRUE` but get the same result as before, I updated the question to show this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`write_json` takes as argument an object to be serialized. So you should do:

```
ls <- list(fruit = c("apples", "oranges"), animals = c("cats","dogs"))
write_json(ls, "test.json", pretty = TRUE)
```

and not `write_json(toJSON(ls), ......)`.

Comment: Here, data.frame is also accepted (data.frame is a kind of list.)